# Grab where CURDATE() and the day before with MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
offers.date = CURDATE()
```

I what I currently have.

It grabs offers for today, but I also would like to grab the orders for yesterday.

How can I do this, without specifying the yesterday's date?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To use CURDATE minus or plus a interval (e.g. yesterday) you can use the [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY);
```

So, in your case you use it like this:

```
WHERE offers.date = CURDATE() OR offers.date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

Optionally you can also use the DATE_SUB() function and instead of a negative interval use the same interval but positive.

Thus, `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)` would become `DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Comment: whats wrong in doing (CURDATE()-1) : its working fine.

Comment: @murtaza.webdev that doesn't work in all circumstances: if CURDATE() is the first of June, subtracting 1 would lead to 0 June.. See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3958

Answer (score 13):

Seems to me like it would be simpler to just say the following

```
WHERE offers.date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 day
```

Answer (score 5):

Building on @edwardmp's answer, I find this syntax slightly more readable than using `DATE_ADD()`:

```
current_date() - interval 1 day
```

Also I would use `IN` instead of `OR` to make it easier to combine this with the rest of your where clause without having to worry too much about parentheses:

```
WHERE offers.date in (current_date(), current_date() - interval 1 day)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could also be

```
  offers.date between (current_date() - interval 1 day) and current_date
```

NB: that this will fail if offers.date is a datetime value because (2017-01-02) < (2017-01-02 12:34:56) due to the fact 2017-01-02 is actually 2017-01-02 00:00:00.